# Is there any tool for defining roles and relationship of game dynamics

Tags: dynamic, game-engine, game-physics, multi-user, game-maker

We want to develop a game for multi user can play at the same time with together in browser. This game will be text-based. It has a strong scenario. But some roles,skills,experience etc. are not clear.

We are searching a tool to manage and defining roles and dynamics of the game. Do you know any tool like this.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What do you mean by "a tool to manage and defining roles and dynamics of the game" ?

Comment: I mean that, there are a lot of roles in the game like engineers,medics,soldiers and their relations and their strength balance is very important. I just want to develop and model them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such "tool" to magically manage the balance of different character classes in any game, if that's what you're looking for. You'll have to make your game and test it, a lot.

If you have say, stats such as strength, critical chance, evasion chance, precision, attack speed, etc., then it's relatively simple to make a simulation where you just specify two characters and let them fight against each other.

But this question is overall way too generic for a precise answer and is poorly tagged. And I wouldn't recommend using Game Maker for a text-based game.